# How to fix Dictionary get() Method in python 'list index out of range'

Tags: python, dictionary, search, get

I execute a url request substituting values ​​into it and get data in the following format

```
{'retCode': 0, 'retMsg': 'OK', 'result': {'category': 'linear', 'list': [{'symbol ': 'XRPUSDT', 'bidPrice': '0.4089'}]}}
```

and I need to get bidprice from it, I use the `get()` method so that in case of an error

> (lack of value in the url)

I save the value None, but I get the error

> list index out of range

```
json.get('result', {}).get('list', {})[0].get('lastPrice')
```

Comment: what did you try to debug? Did you try to replace the one liner with multiple lines and see step by step execution? The sample input does not raise error.

Comment: You should use `try: json['result']['list'][0]... except (KeyError, IndexError): ...` instead of this complex (and wrong) multi-level `get`.

Comment: And don't use `json` as variable name, it is module in Standard Library

Comment: The implication of *get('list', {})[0]* is that the value associated with the key 'list' is subscriptable yet your default is a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 problems I can see:

1. Don't use json as a variable name because it's a standard lib
2. You look for the first element of a list which can be empty
3. Your second 'get' return a dictionary if there is no key called 'list' in the dictionary 'result'.

Here is a solution:

```
    def get_bid_price(json_returned):
        result_list = json_returned.get('result', {}).get('list', [{}])
        if result_list:
            return result_list[0].get('bidPrice')
```

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of the dictionary structure shown in the question you probably want:

```
print(_dict.get('result', {}).get('list', [{}])[0].get('lastPrice'))
```

Note the change to the default when getting 'list'